# Parallels app starts from hotkey - not wanted

Tags: parallels-desktop, shortcut

I have an annoying situation where some key combination, not even sure which, starts up an app in a Parallels VM running Windows, Parallels build 8.0.18619. The app is Chrome. Normally the VM in question is not running. So what happens is that I am furiously typing away, hit the oddball combination, and the VM starts up and Chrome loads.

I don't see where this is set up. It is not set up in OS X, cannot find anything in Parallels, and it is not set up in Windows either. It would seem that it has to be in OS X, because otherwise how could it start up the VM?

As a workaround, I have unintalled Chrome.

I would like to unassign this rogue shortcut. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of parallels?

Comment: Edited build into question above.